# Pygame is always sensing collision between two rect objects

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

As soon as I run the code, Pygame returns that Bird and Pipe are colliding, even when they are obviously not.

I have tried using the `colliderect` function and added a `get_rect` to each of the pictures that I am rendering onto the screen

code:

```
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 750))
gravity = 0


class Pipe(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_change, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x_change = x_change
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pic1 = pygame.image.load('file/path.png')
        self.pic1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.pic1, (28*2, 600*2)).convert_alpha()
        self.pic2 = pygame.image.load('file/path.png')
        self.pic2 = pygame.transform.scale(self.pic2, (28*2, 600*2)).convert_alpha()
        self.rect1 = self.pic1.get_rect()
        self.rect2 = self.pic2.get_rect()

    def collision(self, sprite):
        return self.rect1.colliderect(sprite) or self.rect2.colliderect(sprite)


class Bird(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bird_width, bird_height, y_change, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.pic = pygame.image.load('file/path.png').convert_alpha()
        self.pic = pygame.transform.scale(self.pic, (bird_width, bird_height))
        self.rect = self.pic.get_rect()
        self.bird_width = bird_width
        self.bird_height = bird_height
        self.y_change = y_change
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.velocity = 0
        self.term_velocity = 15


bird = Bird(40, 30, 5, 0, 0)
pipe = Pipe(3, 500, randint(30, 650))

while True:
    if pipe.collision(bird.pic.get_rect()):
        print('collision')
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    gravity += 0.01
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
```

**EDIT:**
After following the advice from Hoog below, the position of both the rects are 0, 0.  How would I change the position of the `get_rect()`?

Comment: If you don't have enough code, just let me know :) ! I wasn't sure how much I should put in in fear of downvotes... I will edit the question if you need me to.

Comment: Definitely more code, you should aim for a Minimal Complete Problem.  Something I can copy-paste onto my machine and get the same error message immediately.  If you would need more than say 50 lines then you should spend time reducing your code to only what is necessary to show the issue you are having.  Something you could do first is print out the rect's positions and sizes so you can check manually if the numbers make sense for a collision (the numbers might not  correspond to exactly what you expect).

Comment: What is `sprite` in this context?

Comment: My guess is that you don't actually use rects for the positioning of your game objects, and that both rects have a position of `(0, 0)`....

Comment: @Hoog, I changed my question code... hopefully this answers your question.  P.S. Sorry for the late response, I had to take care of some stuff.  :)    EDIT: The x and y position of the rect ARE 0, 0 after all!  I'll edit my question in a moment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually answered my own question.  Where I say `get_rect()`, the position of the `rect` is (0, 0).  I figured this out thanks to the comments above. I needed to say:
 `self.rect = self.pic.get_rect(center=(self.x, self.y))` Now, I have it working.